# Minecraft hat not awarding

Tags: bug, status-completed, winterbash

Currently, I have [2 answers and 1 question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user:9752%20%5Bminecraft%5D%20votes:1) (with a score >= 1) in the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag dated after the start of the hat dash.

Yet, I find myself in green fields, with no hat on my head. What gives?

Comment: This is being looked into. ♪

Comment: @GraceNote Cool, thank you. If it helps at all, that last question was also my 10th one and got me the Wampa Kappa.

Comment: One of your answers is on a question that predates Hat Dash. That apparently is the cause, we'll see what we can  fix on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the "3 upvoted posts in a tag" hats, we weren't counting answers to questions that were asked before Hat Dash began.

This is fixed now, so 1 Link's Hat, 1 Un-hat, 3 Dragon-slayer Helms, 1 Tank Hat, and 2 Mining Hats (including yours) were just awarded.

Comment: hats are serious business, its good that you've corrected this mistake

Comment: Serious business indeed. Thanks for looking into it. On behat of everyone who was just hatted a hat, I'd like to hat you. Hats.